# Vb6 error calling stored procedure

Tags: vb6

I keep getting an error when I run this code from the error handler.

All I need to do is pass a variable to the stored procedure I have created, 
I have a form that which contains a List View and a reactivate button.

When I select the questionnaire in the List view and then click reactivate it should send the valid questionnaire ID to the stored procedure.

Here is the code :

```
Private Sub btnReActivate_Click()
    strModuleName = "frmReport.Reactivate"
    Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set oConn = GetConnection

    If oConn.State = adStateOpen Then
        Set objCmd = Nothing
        With objCmd
            .CommandText = "sproc_Reactivate"
            .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
            .ActiveConnection = oConn
            ' Refresh the parameters collection and populate it
            .Parameters.Append _
                objCmd.CreateParameter("@ID", adInteger, adParamInput, , Mid(LV.SelectedItem.Key, 2, Len(LV.SelectedItem.Key) - 2))
        End With
        ' Execute the command
        objCmd.Execute
    End If

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox GetMessage("frmModule1", 1, True, "Module: " & strModuleName & " Line: " & Erl & " - " & Err.Number, Err.Description), vbCritical, "Manage"
End Sub
```

I'm getting: "An error occurred ref:[Module frmReport.Reactivate Line: 0-0]-[]"

Comment: You didn't mention the error you get. Maybe also comment out the `On Error` statement temporarily and let the debugger catch it instead. As a side remark, your title is not very constructive and the actual problem has nothing to do with the fact that there is an error handling statement. You should change it to reflect the problem (ADODB); this'll also help attract the right people.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse. I have altered the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a little bit incomplete, as it is missing the ErrorHandler part, but is there an `Exit Sub` before the `ErrorHandler:` label? It almost seems, from the error, that the function succeeds but then falls into the ErrorHandler routine via normal code flow.

Usually, in VB6, the error handler form is:

```
On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler

... lots of code here

'If we reach this point, we have a successful exit
Exit Sub

MyErrorHandler:
... Code to display/handle error here ....
```

Comment: You can confirm this is the case by `Erl`, `Err.Number` and `Err.Description` all being blank/0.